# Миклухо-Маклай - происхождение фамилии

Tags: имена-собственные

Путешественника и этнографа Миклухо-Маклая знает любое сколько-нибудь образованный человек. Но мне всегда было интересно, откуда взялась у русского человека такая странная фамилия?
Расскажите, пожалуйста. Может, у него иностранные корни? Тогда какие?
Извините, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых "фамилия" совершенно руcская, "русее" некуда, во-вторых, это псевдоним.
Настоящая фамилия Николая Николаевича - Миклуха. Судя по всему, она тоже образована от уменьшительного к имени Николай, но следы этого теряются. 
Первым носителем фамилии, давшей стране немало известных людей, был прадед путешественника, известный как казак Миклуха, получивший за храбрость в Очаковской битве потомственное дворянство. Можно предположить, что это и было его именем.

Родословную можно проследить в статье об отце Николая Николаевича, известном инженере-путейце, строителе Николаевской дороги, но впавшем в немилость за сочувствие к опальному Шевченко.

[Миклуха, Николай Ильич | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%2C_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%98%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B8%D1%87)

По рассказам, это имя (в варианте "Миклухо") - вроде бы было популярно еще и в Новгородских землях, где родился уже сам Николай Николаевич (как туда попала семья, мне неизвестно, возможно оттуда происходила мать Николая Николаевича, Елена Семеновна)

А "Маклай" - слегка измененный вариант его детского прозвища "Миклай", которое тоже является производным от "Николай". Так что Николай Николаевич - четырежды Николай.

О том, почему он изменил одну букву во второй части своей фамилии-псевдонима, слышал версию, что "Миклай" в исходной форме напоминало ему прозвище вислоухого. Якобы это по собачьей кличке,  "Миклай" чем-то действительно напоминает популярные клички борзых: Докучай, Заливай, Заграй. Но это совсем уже недостоверно.

Answer (score 0):

Относительно своего происхождения Миклухо-Маклай собственноручно сделал заметки на полях рукописи очерка о своей жизни и путешествиях, который ему предоставил для ознакомления Е.С. Томассен: 
My ancestors came originally from the Ukraine, and were Zaporogg-cossacks of the Dnieper. After the annexation of the Ukraine, Stepan, one of the family, served as sotnik (a superior Cossack officer) under General Count Rumianzoff, and having distinguished himself at the storming of the Turkish fortress of Otshakoff, was by ukase of Catherine II created a noble... ( Thomassen E. S. «A Biographical Sketch of Nicholas de Miklouho Maclay: the explorer». — Brisbane: Black, Printers, 1882.;   «Mr. E. S. Thomassen» // «The Argus», Monday 27 March 1882, p. 6.

Мои предки родом с Украины, и были запорожскими казаками с Днепра. После аннексии Украины Степан, один из членов семьи, служил сотником (высшее казачье офицерское звание) под командованием генерала графа Румянцева и отличился при штурме турецкой крепости Очаков, указом Екатерины II ему было пожаловано дворянство...

Отец Николай Ильич - украинец, дворянин, родом из Стародуба Черниговской губернии, его предки - знаменитые запорожские казаки.

Мать, Екатерина Семеновна, происходила из смешанной семьи русифицированного немца С. Ф. Беккера - врача, участника войны 1812 года, подполковника в отставке и польской дворянки Лидии Шатковский.